# How to get records from table based on conditions

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Select only latest amount, if null then before that.

table a

```
customer|amount|date
001|2   |20201101
001|null|20201102
001|3   |20201103
002|8.9 |20201101
002|7   |20201008
002|null|20201106
```

Result

```
001|null|20201101
001|null|20201102
001|3   |20201103
002|null|20201101
002|null|20201008
002|7   |20201106
```

amount data should be taken latest as per date , other record will be null, if amount is null for the latest date it should take the previous not null value.
My current attempt:

```
select top 1 [amount] 
from table 
where [amount] is not null 
order by date desc
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using - you tagged three very different database products?

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Currently i am using redhift

Comment: select top 1 [amount] from table
 where customer_code='001' and [amount] is not null order by date desc

Comment: @Rupesh I think you need to be more specific with your question. Do you want to filter rows or have the amount column filled based on a condition? In your example amount 2 is shown as null because it's not the latest amount?

Comment: What is the problem with your current attempt?

Comment: @PhilippJohannis i don't want to filter , please find the details i have modified in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set all but the most recent value to `NULL`:

```
select customer_code, date,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then amount end) as amount
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_code order by (amount is not null) desc, date desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where customer_code = '001'
order by date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you are looking for is a window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
             row_number() over 
             (partition by customer 
              order by amount desc, date desc) as rn
      FROM your_table
      WHERE amount is not null)
WHERE rn = 1
```

You can use [row_number](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html) or [dense_rank](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_DENSE_RANK.html) depending on your needs

Answer (score 0):

Create a view that returns all inserted values in descending order. Then select the first or second row according to the condition.